# Dos set directory with quotes not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to achieve this:

```
set MINIFYEXE = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier\ajaxmin.exe"
echo %MINIFYEXE%
```

Expected is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier\ajaxmin.exe"
```

Output is:

```
ECHO is off.
```

Comment: Don't confuse DOS with some command-interpreter in Windows. DOS is an OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing the spaces before and after the equal sign in your SET statement:

```
set MINIFYEXE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Microsoft Ajax Minifier\ajaxmin.exe"
```

Comment: ahhh, too much c# coding. spaces are a habit.

Comment: @Valamas You should see the crimes against C# I commit when I've done too much VB6 coding.

Comment: @Valamas: Just in case you are curious to know what happens to a variable you create with a SET command that has spaces around `=`. Issue these two commands (from the command prompt): `SET test=value1`, `SET test = value2`. Then issue `SET test`. You will see that the two commands have actually initialised two distinct variables. The second variable contains a space at the end of its name and a space at the beginning of its value.

Comment: I think i feel spoiled by my Visual Studio IDE. Thanks for the explanation.